# Replace "$" in a string in R

Tags: r, string

I would like to replace `$` in my R strings. I have tried:

```
mystring <- "file.tree.id$HASHd15962267-44c21f1cee1057d95d6840$HASHe92451fece3b3341962516acfa962b2f$checked"

 stringr::str_replace(mystring, pattern="$", 
              replacement="!")
```

However, it fails and my replacement character is put as the last character in my original string:

```
[1] "file.tree.id$HASHd15962267-44c21f1cee1057d95d6840$HASHe92451fece3b3341962516acfa962b2f$checked!"
```

I tried some variation using  `"pattern="/$"` but it fails as well. Can someone point a strategy to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need `fixed` to be wrapped as by default `pattern` is in `regex` mode and in regex `$` implies the end of string

```
stringr::str_replace_all(mystring, pattern = fixed("$"), 
              replacement = "!")
```

Or could escape (`\\$`) or place it in square brackets (`[$]$`), but `fixed would be more faster

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However it seems to replace only the first `$` in the string.
 stringr::str_replace(mystring, pattern = fixed("$"), 
+                      replacement = "!")
[1] "file.tree.id!HASHd15962267-44c21f1cee1057d95d6840$HASHe92451fece3b3341962516acfa962b2f$checked"

Comment: @user3091668 sorry, didn't check your string earlier.  You need `str_replace_all`, because `str_replace` only does the replacement on the first instance

Answer (score 3):

In base R, You could use:

```
chartr("$","!", mystring)
[1] "file.tree.id!HASHd15962267-44c21f1cee1057d95d6840!HASHe92451fece3b3341962516acfa962b2f!checked"
```

Or even

```
 gsub("$","!", mystring, fixed = TRUE)
```